# Can you bundle an Objective-C iPhone app and an HTML5 (PhoneGap) iPad app to make one universal app?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, ipad, cordova

The apps provide the same functionality, but have different code bases.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix phonegap and native code fairly easily - just have the startup code check the platform type and display either the native view or the phonegap webview.

However, whatever you do at this point will result in some inconvenience to users - the only way to share in app purchases across devices is to have a single universal app. If you want to keep existing purchases, you have to add an ipad view to the existing iphone app, but that will not show up as an update for anyone who has the existing iPad app.

There are other possibilities such as setting up a server to track purchases in both apps, but that gets a lot more complicated than standard in app purchase and only works if your app includes a login system.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I update the iPhone app to make it universal, and then add the platform type check at startup (iPhone? load Obj-C code / iPad? load HTML5 code) - wouldn't that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, the technical part is easy. The issue is that the app store currently sees them as two entirely different apps, and combining them into a universal app means losing one of the existing app ids.

Comment: That's fine; currently only the iPhone has IAP. It will be added to the iPad after it's "merged" into a universal app. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "bundle" in this instance.  PhoneGap provides the ability to deploy your app to numerous platforms (iOS, Android, Windows Phone) by writing in just HTML5, CSS, and Javascript.  Your question states that you have a functioning HTML5 version of the app written for the PhoneGap platform.  If this is the case, what is the need for the Objective-C iPhone app?  Simply maintaining the HTML5 app should be sufficient to deploy to both iPad and iPhone.  PhoneGap currently supports iOS, iPad, and retina displays.

From the [PhoneGap documentation](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml), you can specify differences in your interface using `config.xml`.

Comment: The native app allows for in-app purchases; this feature will be added to the HTML5 app. However, since the apps are currently distributed separately, users will not be able to transfer their purchases/subscriptions from the iPhone app to the iPad app and vice versa. Hence the idea for a "bundle" app.